# Getting rid of a default where specification

Tags: forest

I specified a `where`declaration in order to align all words in a tree at the base level. My book probably contains one tree that does not fit this default. How do I get rid of the default so that Specifier and Adjunct are not pushed down to the baseline?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges
[XP
  [Specifier]
  [X'
    [Adjunct]
    [X'
      [Complement] [X] ] ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locally set the `tier` to be empty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges,
where n children=0{tier=}{}
[X
  [Specifier]
  [X'
    [Adjunct]
    [X'
      [Complement] [X] ] ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]