# aligning glosses on the baseline

Tags: forest, linguistics

I got code for glossing leaves in linguistic trees. Unfortunately the glossings seem to be not aligned to a common baseline. This is hardly visible when the glosses are in Latin but with Chinese characters they are really jumping.

[image]

In the German glossing, `Ann` seems to be lower than the other glosses. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}



\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

% specification for all trees, "default preamble" appends to existing specification.
% The version with apostrophe replaces it.
\forestset{default preamble'={
    for tree={align=center,parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,anchor=north,base=bottom},
% This would align trees to the baseline. We do not want this for TAG
% where several trees have to be aligned with respect to their center.
%    before drawing tree={
%      sort by=y,
%      for min={tree}{baseline}
%    }
  }}


\forestset{
  declare dimen={child anchor yshift}{0pt},
  adjust childrens child anchors/.style={
    if n children>=2{
      before packing={
        tempdima/.max={max_y}{children},
        for children={
          child anchor yshift=tempdima()-max_y()
        },
      }
    }{}
  },
  default preamble={
    for tree={
      edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)--([yshift=\forestoption{child anchor yshift}].child anchor)},
      adjust childrens child anchors
    }
  },
}

% The following code fixes the size of triangles for examples with translations. The specification
% ",delay=with translation" at the leaves is important to make this work.
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167978/smaller-roofs-for-forest/205311#205311
\forestset{
  with translation/.style={
    l sep=0,inner xsep=0,
    append translation/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\gettranslation{##1}}{content},
    content/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\gettext{##1}}{content},
  },
  append translation/.style={
    if={strequal("#1","")}{}{
      append={[#1,no edge,inner xsep=0,inner ysep=0,outer ysep=0,
               l=\baselineskip + 0.2ex,
        ]}
    }
  }
}

\def\gettext#1{\gettextA#1;;\endget}
\def\gettextA#1;#2;{\removesep#1;}
\def\gettranslation#1{\gettranslationA#1;;\endget}
\def\gettranslationA#1;#2;{\removesep#2;}
\def\removesep#1;#2\endget{#1}


% a specific style that specifies the word tier: all nodes that do not have any children
% to do: make this style default and change all other figures explicitely as is described here:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167983/getting-rid-of-a-default-where-specification
\forestset{
sm edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,base=top}, % changed base=bottom
                                % to top since we have NP and AVM nodes and the NP has to start
                                % right away at the same hight as the AVM St. Mü. 18.10.2017
                 where n children=0{tier=word,delay=with translation}{} %,delay=with translation
                 },
}

\robustify\textsc
\robustify\textit


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sm edges
[CP
[C$'$
        [C$^0$[that; \textsc{comp}]]
        [IP
                [NP[Ann; Ann,roof]]
                [I$'$
                        [I$^0$[will; \textsc{aux}]]
                        [VP
                                [V$'$
                                        [V$^0$[read; 读]]
                                        [NP[the newspaper; \textsc{det} 报纸, roof]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}


\begin{forest}
sm edges
[CP
[C$'$
        [C$^0$[that; dass]]
        [IP
                [NP[Ann; Ann,roof]]
                [I$'$
                        [I$^0$[will; wird]]
                        [VP
                                [V$'$
                                        [V$^0$[read; lesen]]
                                        [NP[the newspaper; die Zeitung, roof]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}



\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The solution works well for most of my trees but it does not work when the words to be glossed are not at the baseline. I did experiment with having a different gloss style for my TAG trees, but then the problem reappears:
[image]

AUX and John and tell and Sam are not aligned.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because not all nodes in the gloss have the same height. One way to solve the problem is by tier-alignment, simply add `tier=gloss` into the definition of `append translation`, like this:

```
\forestset{
  append translation/.style={
    if={strequal("#1","")}{}{
      append={[#1,no edge,inner xsep=0,inner ysep=0,outer ysep=0,
               tier=gloss,
               l=\baselineskip + 0.2ex,
        ]}
    }
  }
}
```

Another solution, in the hope that it works for the problem in the edit.

The image below highlights the original problem by drawing the node edges. The `inner ysep` of the glossed material is set so that the words are nicely separated from the lines above. However, as `tikz`'s has no separate options for the top and bottom margin, this creates a problem below. The depth plus `inner ysep` of the glossed material are large enough that `l=\baselineskip + 0.2ex` of the gloss has no effect whatsoever, at least in the OP's example.

[image: Highlighting the problem]

A way to solve this problem is to set all `inner ysep`'s to `0` and simulate it by struts. Below, I define two commands, `\glossedstrut` and `\glossstrut`, which control the height and depth of the words and their glosses. While these are acutally enough to control the vertical space between a word and its gloss, I also add a `l sep` to the word (this pushes the gloss a bit down), so that the edges of the nodes are sensible.

Here are the styles that achieve the desired alignment:

```
\def\glossedstrut{\rule[-0.8ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}}
\let\glossstrut\strut
\forestset{
  with translation/.style={
    l sep=0,inner xsep=0,
    +content format={\noexpand\glossedstrut}, inner ysep=0, l sep=0.1ex,
    append translation/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\gettranslation{##1}}{content},
    content/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\gettext{##1}}{content},
  },
  append translation/.style={
    if={strequal("#1","")}{}{
      append={[#1,no edge,inner xsep=0,inner ysep=0,outer ysep=0,
        l=0, +content format={\noexpand\glossstrut},
        ]}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for the general case. See edit.